# Como traduzir (ou editar) mensagens de validação ou "labels" em plugins wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugin, filter, label

Como exemplo, instalei um plugin para adicionar um campo de upload de anexos no comments form do Wordpress- https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-attachment/  Como posso alterar os textos em "attachmentRules" e "choose file" usando o functions.php no meu child-theme?

PrtSc do comment form com firebug aberto: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA1IuXMUSGIcG5CenFpMDB4RHM/view?usp=sharing

```
<!-- HTML começa aqui-->

<p class="comment-form-url comment-form-attachment"><label for="attachment">Adicione um anexo<small class="attachmentRules">&nbsp;&nbsp;(Allowed file types: <strong>jpg, gif, png, pdf, doc, docx</strong>, maximum file size: <strong>2MB.</strong></small></label></p>
<p class="comment-form-url comment-form-attachment"><input id="attachment" name="attachment" type="file"></p>

<!-- HTML termina aqui -->
```

Comment: Adicionei alguns filtros no functions.php do child-theme no site wordpress que estou a montar, ora após pesquisa ora com ajuda de autores de plugins. Contudo, por vezes não os encontro e vejo que estou muito limitado não sabendo como manipular essas variáveis nos diferentes plugins que têm as features que necessito mas raramente em Português. Se alguém puder partihar indicações de como posso me tornar mais autónomo nestas situações, seria be mais valioso do que uma qualquer receita para uma qualquer situação específica. No codecademy está a levar algum tempo para dominar funções em php :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo bom plugin ou tema do Wordpress tem arquivos de tradução.

Este plugin que você está usando não é diferente. Dentro da pasta do plugin tem uma pasta chamada 'languages' com dois arquivos 'comment-attachment-de_DE.po' e 'comment-attachment-de_DE.mo'

O nome desses arquivos é dividido em 3 partes:

1. O nome do plugin 'comment-attachment'. Assim o Wordpress vai saber a que plugin se refere aquele arquivo.
2. O código da língua e do país a que se refere. As duas primeiras letras minúsculas referem-se à [língua](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Language-Codes.html#Language-Codes) e as duas letras maiúsculas ao [país](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Country-Codes.html#Country-Codes).
3. A extensão do arquivo .po ou .mo. O arquivo .po é o que vamos editar e o .mo é o utilizado pelo Wordpress para carregar a tradução.

Apesar de poder abrir esses arquivos em um editor de texto, para editar os arquivos .po com segurança você precisará de um programa. Indico o [Poedit](http://poedit.net/).

Agora é só abrir o arquivo .po com o Poedit, alterar as traduções de Alemão para português e salvar o arquivo como 'comment-attachment-pt_PT.po'. O Poedit vai gerar automaticamente um arquivo com a extensão .mo no mesmo diretório.

Você deve então subir os dois arquivos 'comment-attachment-pt_PT.po' e 'comment-attachment-pt_PT.mo' para a pasta wp-content/languages/plugins. E pronto! O plugin está traduzido.

É importante que a língua do seu Wordpress seja pt_PT também. Para isso é só alterar o wp_config.php e adicionar (ou alterar) a linha `define ('WPLANG', 'pt_PT');`.

Depois de fazer a tradução entra em contato com o autor do plugin para que ele a adicione ao pacote.

Comment: Valeu! Já me aventurei na tradução do plugin. E nas frases a traduzir inclui "Allowed File Types", mas não inclui o "Choose File" ou "Browse", que se encontra no botão para procurar o ficheiro para upload. Também não inclui a mensagem "No file chosen", que se encontra ao lado do botão. Será possível alterar estes textos de outra forma, usando o functions.php ou criando um ficheiro de javascript, na pasta do meu child-theme?

Comment: Provavelmente esse campos são de tags <input type="file"> e a exibição desse campo depende da língua em que o navegador está. Neste caso você vai precisar alterar com js e css. Na verdade o jeito mais prático é ocultar todo o input com css opacity:0 e inserir com js o texto que você quer.